# Extract range of elements from plsql Associative array

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I am currently on **oracle 11.2**. Below is a snippet of the code.I want to extract range of elements from record type on every page number passed.
Rather than in the query itself I want to extract from the table type.

suppose the collection is filled with 13 records
`page` passed with `1` should give elements from `1 to 5`

```
page =2 -> 6 to 10  
page =3 -> 11 to 13
```

I don't want to put page logic in the select statement.
I am not getting the correct output when i pass `page 2` and on wards.
I don't have the exact code right now,but when I go to office tomorrow morning,I will update the correct code which is inside the loop.

```
create or replace procedure p1 (page number) is
 TYPE rec_typ IS RECORD (col1 VARCHAR2(5),col2 VARCHAR2(50),col3 
    number(10));
    TYPE rec_tab IS TABLE OF rec_typ INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
      t_tab rec_tab ;
      f_tab rec_tab ;
      n number :=0;
   BEGIN
      Select * bulk collect into t_tab from test;
      For j in p1*5-4..p1*5
    LOOP
    if t_tab.exists(j) then
      n:= n+1;
      f_tab.extend;
      f_tab(n) :=t_tab(j);
   end if;
    END LOOP;
   END;
```

Answer (score 0):

use **LIMIT** Option it will help you!!

refer :  http://www.dba-oracle.com/plsql/t_plsql_limit_clause.htm

**Sample query :** in this code you can pass 13 in your parameter.

```
 create or replace procedure p1 (page number) is
    TYPE rec_typ IS RECORD (col1 VARCHAR2(5),col2 VARCHAR2(50),col3 number(10));
        TYPE rec_tab IS TABLE OF rec_typ INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
          t_tab rec_tab ;
          f_tab rec_tab ;
          n number :=0;
          j number :=1;
    CURSOR C IS
        Select * bulk collect into t_tab from test;
    BEGIN
    OPEN C;
    LOOP
    FETCH C BULK_COLLECT INTO t_tab LIMIT 5;

    EXIT WHEN L_PF.COUNT=0;

    if t_tab.exists(j) then
      n:= n+1;
      f_tab.extend;
      f_tab(n) :=t_tab(j);
   end if;
    j:=j+1;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE C;

    END;
```

Note: Its only for Sample code . Engage this code with your logic. Hope it will help you. if its helpful to you, click useful up tick button, which is left side of this answer.

Comment: Thank you so much.. Sorry for late reply.I completely forgot about LIMIT clause.I think will take over from here

Comment: its oky... Raj have a grt day... if its helpful to you, click useful up tick button, which is left side of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this collection you can use ROWNUM and then use pagination concept here. Hope this below snippet helps.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE p1(
    page NUMBER)
IS
TYPE rec_typ
IS
  RECORD
  (
    col1 VARCHAR2(5),
    col2 VARCHAR2(50),
    col3 NUMBER(10));
TYPE rec_tab
IS
  TABLE OF rec_typ INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  t_tab rec_tab ;
  LV_SQL  VARCHAR2(32676);
  lv_cond VARCHAR2(32676);
BEGIN
  LV_COND:=
  CASE
  WHEN PAGE = 1 THEN
    ' AND a.rn BETWEEN 1 AND 5 '
  WHEN PAGE =2 THEN
    ' AND a.rn BETWEEN 6 AND 10 '
  WHEN PAGE = 3 THEN
    ' AND a.rn BETWEEN 11 AND 15 '
  ELSE
    ''
  END;
  LV_SQL:= 'SELECT                     
            a.col1,                      
            a.col2,                      
            a.col3                    
            FROM                    
            (SELECT T.*,ROWNUM RN FROM TEST T)A                    
            WHERE 1 = 1 '||lv_cond;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lv_sql BULK COLLECT INTO t_tab;
  FOR z IN t_tab.FIRST..t_tab.LAST
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(t_tab(z).col1||' '||t_tab(z).col2||'  '||t_tab(z).col1);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```